# Validation error in HTML5 for custom search from google (gcse:searchbox-only)

Tags: css, html, validation, search

I have the error in wc3 validator. Error is next:

```
 Warning Line 139, Column 49: Element name gcse:searchbox-only cannot be represented as XML 1.0.

                    <div class="search-row"><gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only></div>

    ✉
    Error Line 139, Column 49: Element gcse:searchbox-only not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

                    <div class="search-row"><gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only></div>
```

My search is workin in next compilation: in header page i got search box (i made it  css so my code: `<div class="search-row"><gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only></div>`). In page `www.domain.com/?action=search` is displayed result of search (`<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>`).

How I can remove this error?

**I GOT SOLUTION:**

```
<div class="gcse-searchbox-only"></div>
```

Now validation is green! :-)